# React-Bootstrap Collapse not working with custom components

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've encountered a situation where Collapse does not seem to work properly when it's used to wrap a class component, though it does seem to work correctly when it wraps a simple JSX element.

You can see this in action in this example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/flamboyant-dhawan-4rf4b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Note that in both cases where Collapse is used, it is initialized with `in={false}`, but whereas this works when wrapping a definition list, it does not work when wrapping a custom component that provides a definition list.

Am I misunderstanding how Collapse should be used? Or can anyone suggest a solution to allow Collapse to work as intended when wrapping a class component?

Here's the same code linked above for convenience:

```js
import React from "react";

import Collapse from "react-bootstrap/Collapse";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

import "./App.css";

class BasicList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <dl id={this.props.id} className="row">
        <dt className="col-md-3">Name</dt>
        <dd className="col-md-9">{this.props.name}</dd>

        <dt className="col-md-3">Address</dt>
        <dd className="col-md-9">{this.props.address}</dd>

        <dt className="col-md-3">Favorite Color</dt>
        <dd className="col-md-9">{this.props.color}</dd>
      </dl>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <Container className="p-3">
    <h1 className="header">Collapse Example</h1>

    <p>
      <em>Ex 1: BasicList component that renders a DL</em>
    </p>
    <BasicList
      id="0"
      name="Wednesday Addams"
      address="0001 Cemetery Lane"
      color="black"
    />

    <p>
      <em>
        Ex 2: BasicList component that renders a DL inside a Collapse. It should
        be collapsed, but it is not.
      </em>
    </p>
    <Collapse in={false}>
      <BasicList
        id="1"
        name="Eddie Munster"
        address="1313 Mockingbird Lane"
        color="grey"
      />
    </Collapse>

    <p>
      <em>Ex 3: A simple DL element inside a Collapse. It is collapsed.</em>
    </p>
    <Collapse in={false}>
      <dl id="2" className="row">
        <dt className="col-md-3">Name</dt>
        <dd className="col-md-9">Theodore Cleaver</dd>

        <dt className="col-md-3">Address</dt>
        <dd className="col-md-9">485 Mapleton Drive</dd>

        <dt className="col-md-3">Favorite Color</dt>
        <dd className="col-md-9">Blue</dd>
      </dl>
    </Collapse>
  </Container>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `Collapse` component is collapsed, it adds `.collapse` class to the immediate child element. It's not able to add a class as I can see it in your code since `BasicList` is a component. However, you can wrap `BasicList` component in a `div`.

```
<Collapse in={false}>
    <div>
        <BasicList
            id="1"
            name="Eddie Munster"
            address="1313 Mockingbird Lane"
            color="grey"
        />
    </div>
</Collapse>
```

You can see a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-fog-2bk4m).

Comment: @nbayramberdiyev Awesome, thanks for pointing that out! It was not evident in the react-bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Navbar.Collapse` from `react-bootstrap` as another solution. Let me show you a sample code snippet of looping and creating some NavItems inside a Collpase.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavItem, Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


const SubMenu = (props) => {
    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
    const toggle = () => setCollapsed(!collapsed);
    const { icon, title, items } = props;

    return (
        <div className="w-100">

            <Navbar.Collapse in={!collapsed} className="">
                {items.map((item) => (
                    <NavItem key={item.target} className="ps-5 border">
                        <Nav.Link href={item.target}>
                            {item.title}
                        </Nav.Link>
                    </NavItem>
                ))}
            </Navbar.Collapse>

        </div>
    );
};

export default SubMenu;
```